# SVG Filter with feBlend multiply not working on Chrome 46 for Windows

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-filters

The following code stopped working all of sudden from last week. This works on all browsers expect chrome on windows. Did anybody else faced similar issue?

It is not updating the color, but it works on all other browsers and OS.

```
<filter id="sample-test" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#d9251d" class="color-test" result="tint"></feFlood>
      <feBlend in="tint" in2="SourceGraphic" mode="multiply" result="multiply"></feBlend>
    </filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known new bug in Chrome 46 (#549440) which has just been fixed. the work around is:

```
<filter id="sample-test" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#d9251d" class="color-test" result="tint"></feFlood>
      <feComposite operator="arithmetic" in="tint" in2="SourceGraphic" k1="1" result="multiply"/>
    </filter>
```

Which uses the multiply capability of feComposite. This is apparently a different code path which is not broken.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time and answering

Comment: You could also tint directly by using a feColorMatrix. There's no need to use a feFlood